# Error in deploying dash visualization dashboard on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, drop-down-menu, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, plotly-dash

I have created two seperate dash web apps and integrated them into one by creating tabs. I can easily see the visualization on local host but facing problem in uploading the code. The second tab consists of drop down menus. 
Upon uploading the code on AWS, the drop down menu are not visible.

[Output on Local Host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5zm9.png)

[Output on AWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHkqG.png)

[Jupyter notebook logs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOxir.png)

Here is the code.

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Smoothie Fixed Benefit Prices'),
    html.P("These prices are common for all routes in India."),
    html.P("Peak months are:-Jan,June, July, August, November, December."),
    html.P("Peak Hours ( During Peak Months ):-9 A.M. to Midnight"),
    html.P("Peak Hours ( During Non Peak Months ):-12 P.M. - 12 A.M."),
    html.H3('Select Airline'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='datasource-1',
        options=[
            {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['Low Delay Airlines (6E, UK)','High Delay Airlines (9W,AI,SG,G8)']
        ],
    ),
    html.H3('Select Peak/Non-Peak Month'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='datasource-2',
        options=[
            {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['Peak Month','Non Peak Month']
        ]

    ),   
    html.Hr(),
    html.Div('Select Peak/Non Peak Hour and Threshold Delay'),
    html.Div(
        id='controls-container'
    ),
    html.Hr(),
    html.Div('Output'),
    html.Div(
        id='output-container'
    )
])

def generate_control_id(value):
    return 'Control {}'.format(value)

DYNAMIC_CONTROLS = {
    'Low Delay Airlines (6E, UK)': dcc.Dropdown(
        id=generate_control_id('Low Delay Airlines (6E, UK)'),
        options=[{'label': '{}'.format(i), 'value': i} for i in list(price['Hour Peaks'][price['Airlines']=='Low Delay Airlines (6E, UK)'].unique())]
    ),
    'High Delay Airlines (9W,AI,SG,G8)': dcc.Dropdown(
        id=generate_control_id('High Delay Airlines (9W,AI,SG,G8)'),
        options=[{'label': '{}'.format(i), 'value': i} for i in list(price['Hour Peaks'][price['Airlines']=='High Delay Airlines (9W,AI,SG,G8)'].unique())]
    ),
    'Peak Month': dcc.Dropdown(
        id=generate_control_id('Peak Month'),
        options=[{'label': '{}'.format(i), 'value': i} for i in [60,90,120,150,180]]
    ),
    'Non Peak Month': dcc.Dropdown(
        id=generate_control_id('Non Peak Month'),
        options=[{'label': '{}'.format(i), 'value': i} for i in [60,90,120,150,180]]
    )
}

@app.callback(
    Output('controls-container', 'children'),
    [Input('datasource-1', 'value'),
     Input('datasource-2', 'value')])
def display_controls(datasource_1_value, datasource_2_value):
    # generate 2 dynamic controls based off of the datasource selections
    return html.Div([
        DYNAMIC_CONTROLS[datasource_1_value],
        DYNAMIC_CONTROLS[datasource_2_value],
    ])

def generate_output_id(value1, value2):
    return '{} {} container'.format(value1, value2)

@app.callback(
    Output('output-container', 'children'),
    [Input('datasource-1', 'value'),
     Input('datasource-2', 'value')])
def display_controls(datasource_1_value, datasource_2_value):
    # create a unique output container for each pair of dyanmic controls
    return html.Div(id=generate_output_id(
        datasource_1_value,
        datasource_2_value
    ))
def prem(a,b,c,d):
    return (price['Office Premium ( INR )'][(price['Hour Peaks']==a)&(price['Threshold Delay ( Min )']==b)&(price['Airlines']==c)&(price['Month Peaks']==d)])
def incidence(a,b,c,d):
    return (price['Incidence Rate (%)'][(price['Hour Peaks']==a)&(price['Threshold Delay ( Min )']==b)&(price['Airlines']==c)&(price['Month Peaks']==d)])

def generate_output_callback(datasource_1_value, datasource_2_value):
    def output_callback(control_1_value, control_2_value):
        # This function can display different outputs depending on
        # the values of the dynamic controls
        premium=prem(control_1_value,control_2_value,datasource_1_value,datasource_2_value)
        incidence_rate=incidence(control_1_value,control_2_value,datasource_1_value,datasource_2_value)
        return '''
            For the selected values, premium in INR is {} and incidence rate is {} %
        '''.format(
            list(premium)[0],
            list(incidence_rate)[0]
            )
    return output_callback

app.config.supress_callback_exceptions = True

# create a callback for all possible combinations of dynamic controls
# each unique dynamic control pairing is linked to a dynamic output component
for value1, value2 in itertools.product(
        [o['value'] for o in app.layout['datasource-1'].options],
        [o['value'] for o in app.layout['datasource-2'].options]):
    app.callback(
        Output(generate_output_id(value1, value2), 'children'),
        [Input(generate_control_id(value1), 'value'),
         Input(generate_control_id(value2), 'value')])(
        generate_output_callback(value1, value2)
    )
```

Code for both apps combined

```
server = Flask(__name__)

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

application = app.server

available_indicators = df['Indicator Name'].unique()

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Tabs(id="tabs", children=[
        dcc.Tab(label='Delay Comparison', children=[
    html.Div([
        html.H3('Flight Delays'),
        html.H3('Comparison of delay over different routes and different months'),
        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='crossfilter-xaxis-column',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in available_indicators],
                value='6E'
            ),
            dcc.RadioItems(
                id='crossfilter-xaxis-type',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['Linear']],
                value='Linear',
                labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'}
            )
        ],
        style={'width': '49%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='crossfilter-yaxis-column',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in available_indicators],
                value='6E'
            ),
            dcc.RadioItems(
                id='crossfilter-yaxis-type',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['Linear']],
                value='Linear',
                labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'}
            )
        ], style={'width': '49%', 'float': 'right', 'display': 'inline-block'})
    ], style={
        'borderBottom': 'thin lightgrey solid',
        'backgroundColor': 'rgb(250, 250, 250)',
        'padding': '10px 5px'
    }),

    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(
            id='crossfilter-indicator-scatter',
            hoverData={'points': [{'customdata': 'MUM-DEL'}]}
        )
    ], style={'width': '49%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'padding': '0 20'}),
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='x-time-series'),
        dcc.Graph(id='y-time-series'),
    ], style={'display': 'inline-block', 'width': '49%'}),

    html.Div(dcc.Slider(
        id='crossfilter-year--slider',
        min=df['Year'].min(),
        max=df['Year'].max(),
        value=df['Year'].max(),
        marks={str(year): str(year) for year in df['Year'].unique()}
    ), style={'width': '49%', 'padding': '0px 20px 20px 20px'}),
    html.Div([html.H6('Months',style={'width': '49%', 'padding': '0px 20px 20px 285px','fontColor':'#7ad5f9'})],style={'fontColor': 'blue'})
]),
        dcc.Tab(label='Pricing', children=[
            html.H3('Smoothie Fixed Benefit Prices'),
    html.P("These prices are common for all routes in India."),
    html.P("Peak months are:-Jan,June, July, August, November, December."),
    html.P("Peak Hours ( During Peak Months ):-9 A.M. to Midnight"),
    html.P("Peak Hours ( During Non Peak Months ):-12 P.M. - 12 A.M."),
    html.H3('Select Airline'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='datasource-1',
        options=[
            {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['Low Delay Airlines (6E, UK)','High Delay Airlines (9W,AI,SG,G8)']
        ],
    ),
    html.H3('Select Peak/Non-Peak Month'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='datasource-2',
        options=[
            {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['Peak Month','Non Peak Month']
        ]

    ),   
    html.Hr(),
    html.Div('Select Peak/Non Peak Hour and Threshold Delay'),
    html.Div(
        id='controls-container'
    ),
    html.Hr(),
    html.Div('Output'),
    html.Div(
        id='output-container'
    )
])
    ])
])
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('crossfilter-indicator-scatter', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('crossfilter-xaxis-column', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('crossfilter-yaxis-column', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('crossfilter-xaxis-type', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('crossfilter-yaxis-type', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('crossfilter-year--slider', 'value')])
def update_graph(xaxis_column_name, yaxis_column_name,
                 xaxis_type, yaxis_type,
                 year_value):
    dff = df[df['Year'] == year_value]

    return {
        'data': [go.Scatter(
            x=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == xaxis_column_name]['Value'],
            y=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Value'],
            text=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Country Name'],
            customdata=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Country Name'],
            mode='markers',
            marker={
                'size': 15,
                'opacity': 0.5,
                'line': {'width': 0.5, 'color': 'white'}
            }
        )],
        'layout': go.Layout(
            title = 'Comparison of Airline Delay over Different Routes in India',
            xaxis={
                'title': 'First Airline Delay in Minutes',
                'type': 'linear' if xaxis_type == 'Linear' else 'log'
            },
            yaxis={
                'title': 'Second Airline Delay in Minutes',
                'type': 'linear' if yaxis_type == 'Linear' else 'log'
            },
            margin={'l': 40, 'b': 30, 't': 30, 'r': 30},
            height=450,
            hovermode='closest'
        )
    }

def create_time_series(dff, axis_type, title):
    return {
        'data': [go.Scatter(
            x=dff['Year'],
            y=dff['Value'],
            mode='lines+markers'
        )],
        'layout': {
            'height': 225,
            'margin': {'l': 35, 'b': 30, 'r': 10, 't': 10},
            'annotations': [{
                'x': 0, 'y': 0.85, 'xanchor': 'left', 'yanchor': 'bottom',
                'xref': 'paper', 'yref': 'paper', 'showarrow': False,
                'align': 'left', 'bgcolor': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
                'text': title
            }],
            'yaxis': {'type': 'linear' if axis_type == 'Linear' else 'log','title':'Average Delay in Minutes'},
            'xaxis': {'showgrid': False,'title':'Months'}
        }
    }


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('x-time-series', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('crossfilter-indicator-scatter', 'hoverData'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('crossfilter-xaxis-column', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('crossfilter-xaxis-type', 'value')])
def update_y_timeseries(hoverData, xaxis_column_name, axis_type):
    country_name = hoverData['points'][0]['customdata']
    dff = df[df['Country Name'] == country_name]
    dff = dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == xaxis_column_name]
    title = '<b>{}</b><br>{}'.format(country_name, xaxis_column_name)
    return create_time_series(dff, axis_type, title)


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('y-time-series', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('crossfilter-indicator-scatter', 'hoverData'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('crossfilter-yaxis-column', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('crossfilter-yaxis-type', 'value')])
def update_x_timeseries(hoverData, yaxis_column_name, axis_type):
    dff = df[df['Country Name'] == hoverData['points'][0]['customdata']]
    dff = dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]
    return create_time_series(dff, axis_type, yaxis_column_name)
def generate_control_id(value):
    return 'Control {}'.format(value)

DYNAMIC_CONTROLS = {
    'Low Delay Airlines (6E, UK)': dcc.Dropdown(
        id=generate_control_id('Low Delay Airlines (6E, UK)'),
        options=[{'label': '{}'.format(i), 'value': i} for i in list(price['Hour Peaks'][price['Airlines']=='Low Delay Airlines (6E, UK)'].unique())]
    ),
    'High Delay Airlines (9W,AI,SG,G8)': dcc.Dropdown(
        id=generate_control_id('High Delay Airlines (9W,AI,SG,G8)'),
        options=[{'label': '{}'.format(i), 'value': i} for i in list(price['Hour Peaks'][price['Airlines']=='High Delay Airlines (9W,AI,SG,G8)'].unique())]
    ),
    'Peak Month': dcc.Dropdown(
        id=generate_control_id('Peak Month'),
        options=[{'label': '{}'.format(i), 'value': i} for i in [60,90,120,150,180]]
    ),
    'Non Peak Month': dcc.Dropdown(
        id=generate_control_id('Non Peak Month'),
        options=[{'label': '{}'.format(i), 'value': i} for i in [60,90,120,150,180]]
    )
}

@app.callback(
    Output('controls-container', 'children'),
    [Input('datasource-1', 'value'),
     Input('datasource-2', 'value')])
def display_controls(datasource_1_value, datasource_2_value):
    # generate 2 dynamic controls based off of the datasource selections
    return html.Div([
        DYNAMIC_CONTROLS[datasource_1_value],
        DYNAMIC_CONTROLS[datasource_2_value],
    ])

def generate_output_id(value1, value2):
    return '{} {} container'.format(value1, value2)

@app.callback(
    Output('output-container', 'children'),
    [Input('datasource-1', 'value'),
     Input('datasource-2', 'value')])
def display_controls(datasource_1_value, datasource_2_value):
    # create a unique output container for each pair of dyanmic controls
    return html.Div(id=generate_output_id(
        datasource_1_value,
        datasource_2_value
    ))
def prem(a,b,c,d):
    return (price['Office Premium ( INR )'][(price['Hour Peaks']==a)&(price['Threshold Delay ( Min )']==b)&(price['Airlines']==c)&(price['Month Peaks']==d)])
def incidence(a,b,c,d):
    return (price['Incidence Rate (%)'][(price['Hour Peaks']==a)&(price['Threshold Delay ( Min )']==b)&(price['Airlines']==c)&(price['Month Peaks']==d)])

def generate_output_callback(datasource_1_value, datasource_2_value):
    def output_callback(control_1_value, control_2_value):
        # This function can display different outputs depending on
        # the values of the dynamic controls
        premium=prem(control_1_value,control_2_value,datasource_1_value,datasource_2_value)
        incidence_rate=incidence(control_1_value,control_2_value,datasource_1_value,datasource_2_value)
        return '''
            For the selected values, premium in INR is {} and incidence rate is {} %
        '''.format(
            list(premium)[0],
            list(incidence_rate)[0]
            )
    return output_callback

app.config.supress_callback_exceptions = True

# create a callback for all possible combinations of dynamic controls
# each unique dynamic control pairing is linked to a dynamic output component
for value1, value2 in itertools.product(
        [o['value'] for o in app.layout['datasource-1'].options],
        [o['value'] for o in app.layout['datasource-2'].options]):
    app.callback(
        Output(generate_output_id(value1, value2), 'children'),
        [Input(generate_control_id(value1), 'value'),
         Input(generate_control_id(value2), 'value')])(
        generate_output_callback(value1, value2)
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug = False,port=8080)
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you ever resolve this @PrateekSingh?